# Responsive horizontal timeline into vertical timeline with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, timeline

I've tried looking up tutorials/examples/codepens like this but wasn't successful. Please link to any I might have missed.

I'm trying to make this image into html/css/Bootstrap, which shouldn't be so bad, except the vertical line might be a difficult (could use advice on this):
[image]

And then when you're changing the size of your browser or looking at it on portrait on a smartphone, I want it to look more like:

[image]

But I don't know how to go about doing this so that the circle and caption that correspond to each other in the horizontal timeline are also together on the vertical timeline.

Thank you so much for your help! Basic codepens would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```css
.Img1{
 margin-top:30px;
 position:relative;
}
.Img1:before{
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 21px;
    width: 1px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: -26px;
}
.Img1 img{width:100%;border-radius:50%;width:100px;
  height:100px;}
  
  .Text2{
  width:200px;
}

.Img2{
 margin-bottom:30px;
 position:relative;
}
.Img2:before{
      content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 21px;
    width: 1px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: -26px;
}
.Img2 img{width:100%;border-radius:50%;width:100px;
  height:100px;}
.container {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    text-align:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    margin:20px 0;
}
.container:after { content: "\00A0"; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
.container{ display: inline-block;}
html[xmlns] .container { display: block;}
* html .container{ height: 1%;}
.container {display: block}
.Text1 {
    float: right;
    margin:30px 0;
}
.Img1 {
    float: left;
    margin-top:0;
    
}


.Text2 {
    float: left;
    margin:30px 0;
}
.Img2 {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.wrapper{width:60%;margin:0 auto;}
.Img2:before,.Img1:before{display:none;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="Text1">
Idea formed
</div>
<div class="Img1">
<img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="Img2">
<img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png">
</div>
<div class="Text2">
Private funding for prototype raise
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Right now I have used image but you can create a div instead of image. And I have just created structure you need to modify this code.