# How to create responsive horizontal timeline

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to create a simple horizontal timeline where timeline border starts from extreme end of page in case it is horizontal.

Each timeline circle would have card below it.

I tried many solutions but all horizontal lines starting from a particular point and not from one end of screen as per my requirement.

[image: timeline]

---

Referred posts:

- [Responsive horizontal timeline into vertical timeline with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41605804/8111997)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this it is same as your requirement only think to remove the left or right arrow 
https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline

Comment: But the horizontal line does not start from end point of page, that is what i am not able to modify in any of the demo i found.

Comment: Thanks for help kapil. Sorry someone downvoted your answer